# Programmatic text wrapping in TextView

Tags: java, android, text, textview, word-wrap

I'm working on a custom widget for my application to replicate the look of a Preference button for layouts. The issue is the 'summary' text won't wrap when it hits the right wall of the view. One of the goals I'm trying to keep is that this widget is completely made from java with no XML attributes.

Below is the code I'm using to create the text view.

```
public void setSummary(String summary) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(summary)) {
        if (mSummaryView == null) {
            mSummaryView = new TextView(mContext);
            mSummaryView.setTextSize(14);
            mSummaryView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                                            android.R.color.tertiary_text_dark));
            addView(mSummaryView);
        }
        mSummaryView.setText(summary);
        mSummaryView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        if (mSummaryView != null) {
            mSummaryView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    mSummaryText = summary;
}
```

and here is the code I'm using to layout summary view

```
mSummaryView.layout(
            mPreferencePadding + mIconWidth,
            centerVertical + (mCombinedTextHeight / 2) - mSummaryHeight,
            width - mPreferencePadding,
            centerVertical + (mCombinedTextHeight / 2));
```

I've tried to add:

```
mSummaryView.setSingleLine(false);
```

along with quite a few other tricks but they all ended in the same way.

Comment: are you sure that the containing view group is properly constraining the views? if you use a regular text view in place of your view, does it wrap correctly? "One of the goals I'm trying to keep is that this widget is completely made from java with no xml attributes"- that's the opposite of what you should be going for.

Comment: I'm treating this as somewhat of an exercise of learning. I've had success with the text wrapping when including a xml based view.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using XML? XML is one of the foundations of Android development, it has a place and should not be ignored. If it works, use it. Development is about doing what works, quickest, with the least effort; as well as being able to maintain your work easily.

Comment: as stated above your response I'm trying to use this as a learning exercise. I can easily use XML to solve this issue, but I'm hoping to find a way to do this using java.

Comment: @Jeffrey Blattman after further inspection, the XML text view doesn't wrap.

Comment: any answer here is going to involve the container for the view in question. there isn't enough information here to provide an answer.

Comment: Please upload your images to imgur than anywhere else. The link is broken, thus the question now became too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the max width of the [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to the max size of the screen... you may want to consider padding as this will run the full size of the screen

```
// get the screen size
DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
// force view width to only be as wide as the screen
mSummaryView.setMaxWidth(mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels);

// could be a oneliner :P
mSummaryView.setMaxWidth((getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()).widthPixels);
```

Comment: Thanks! That with a little math got me exactly what I was looking for!